# Excel VBA Slow Opening

Tags: excel, vba

We have an excel workbook (xlsm) which has an embedded VBA code, which looks up the distance between two points using the getgoogledistance module.

Since we have added this to the workbook, it take a very long time to open sometimes in excess of 10 minutes..

I suspect on opening the workbook, it is trying to update all of the entries, hence why it is slow to open.

Is there a way in which I could add a button to the worksheet and rather than on 'open' update the necessary cells, when this button is clicked it updated all the cells?

Comment: Yes. You could turn calculation to manual, and then manually update when you want. Check [Change when a worksheet or workbook recalculates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-f38c7793-0367-41ce-b892-dfe54946bd76#__toc305944076)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to go to the options, then customize menu and from the list on the right, check the `Developer` menu.

Back to Excel, you'll be able to add controls such as push buttons and attach macros to them.